# Escaping single quotes in html via Python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to open up an html page via `webrowser` but I can't seem to escape single quotes for proper html parsing.

I am trying both cgi and html escape but both are yielding original string.

```
text = ' Elon Musk: ‘Give People Back Their Goddamn Freedom’'




cgi.escape(text)
 >>> ' Elon Musk: ‘Give People Back Their Goddamn Freedom’'
```

`html.escape` also yields the original string with no escape

Thank you.

UPDATE:

The escapes conversions work fine, using html.escape or cgi, 
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html
but not the quotes around Elon Musk's quote.
So html is not being read properly with `webrowser`

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Just put his character in front of every quote you need to escape: \

```
text = ' Elon Musk: \‘Give People Back Their Goddamn Freedom\’'
```

Comment: That seems to be a Python escape. I need Python to convert it so that html can be correctly parsed. 

https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html